# Rails get difference between two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

How to get time difference in `days,hours,mins`

I am trying to do

```
datetime_A - datetime_B
```

`datetime_A` = Sat, 04 Jan 2014 07:00:13 +0000

`datetime_B` = Fri, 03 Jan 2014 01:09:46 +0000

it returns me something like`(35809/28800)`,bdw what does it means?

I need like `1day,5h,23min`

How can do it?

Comment: give the date values..

Comment: if it's a duplicate why don't you provide a link to the answer

Answer (score 16):

You need to add helper in your rails app to achive this. Ruby not provide any direct way for this. Below is date manipulation using ruby 2.1.0.

```
2.1.0 :021 > a_date_time = DateTime.now
 => Fri, 26 Dec 2014 16:39:30 +0530 # First Date
2.1.0 :022 > b_date_time = DateTime.now-20
 => Sat, 06 Dec 2014 16:40:03 +0530 # Second Date
2.1.0 :023 > (a_date_time - b_date_time).to_i
 => 19 # Direct date difference
2.1.0 :024 > Seconds = ((a_date_time - b_date_time)*24*60*60).to_i
 => 1727966 # Seconds between two dates
2.1.0 :025 > sec = Seconds % 60
 => 26 # Second diffence to print
2.1.0 :026 > Minutes = Seconds / 60
 => 28799 # Minutes between two dates
2.1.0 :027 > min = Minutes % 60
 => 59 # Minute diffence to print
2.1.0 :028 > Hours = Minutes / 60
 => 479 # Hours between two dates
2.1.0 :029 > hour = Hours % 24
 => 23 #Hour diffence to print
2.1.0 :030 > Days = Hours / 24
 => 19 # Days between two dates
2.1.0 :032 > Days.to_s + 'Days, ' + hour.to_s + 'Hours, '+ min.to_s + 'Mins, ' + sec.to_s + 'Secs'
 => "19Days, 23Hours, 59Mins, 26Secs" # Desired output
```

Comment: use date module type `require 'date'` in console and you are good

Answer (score 7):

I like to use the gem `time_diff`

https://github.com/abhidsm/time_diff

Here is a example how it works

```
   Time.diff(Time.parse('2011-03-06'), Time.parse('2011-03-07'))
   # => {:year => 0, :month => 0, :week => 0, :day => 1, :hour => 0, :minute => 0, :second => 0, :diff => '1 day and 00:00:00'}
```

Comment: It might not work with ruby 2.1.0 because in in time difference you can see `distance_in_seconds = ((end_time - start_time).abs).round` This not supporting in latest ruby versions. For older version I will also use this

Answer (score 7):

An alternative could be to use the `ActionView` helper `distance_of_time_in_words` (see the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words)). If normally does not give the exact minor units, but something like "around 5 days".

Answer (score 2):

The value that is being given is a Rational, (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Rational.html). It represents the number of days between the two dates. This is actually quite cool, as it can be much more accurate than a float and easily convertible to hours, minutes, seconds etc.